# rewrite url based on specific sub-directory using.htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am wondering whether it's possible to use .htaccess to search for a particular folder that starts with a number and redirects internally without changing the URL in the browser.

Lets say I have a url like:

```
www.example.com/api/rest/3.22/user
```

Now I want to rewrite the url internally to (for example)

```
www.example.com/api/rest/3.0/user
```

Note: Only the 3.0 folder available in server and 3.22 is just a name.

I tried with the following one,but it not helps.

```
RewriteRule ^api/rest/3\.22/$ /api/rest/3.0/$1
```

Comment: What you want to put to $1 ? :) `RewriteRule ^api/rest/3\.22/(.*)$ /api/rest/3.0/$1`

Comment: It is Just a Query String ?xxx=xxxx

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(api/rest)/(?!3\.0/)[\d.]+/(\w+)$ /$1/3.0/$2 [L,NC]
```